# Check if Lightning component type exist before creation

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, namespace

Is there any way to check dynamically if lightning component of provided type exists?

Here is the thing. I know only type name of the component (e.g. MyTestComponent), and my logic needs to check couple of namespaces in order of preferences and then use the first available:
NS1:MyTestComponent, NS2:MyTestComponent, NS3:MyTestComponent (if all not found, go with c:MyTestComponent)

The question here: is there any better way to check if it's a valid component type before actually creating it?
So far the only way I could think of is like this:

```
try {

    $A.createComponent('NS1:MyTestComponent',{key:'Test'}, function() {} );

catch(exp) {

    try {

        $A.createComponent('NS2:MyTestComponent',{key:'Test'}, function() {} );

    catch(exp) {

        $A.createComponent('NS3:MyTestComponent',{key:'Test'}, function() {} );

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add aura id to your component, and then search for it.

```
if (cmp.find("test1")==undefined) {
    $A.createComponent('NS1:MyTestComponent',{key:'Test', 'aura:id': 'test1'}, function() {});
}
```

> Update: There is a better method. Iterate over v.body , and check
>   items type.
>
> ```
> var dynamicComp = cmp.get("v.body")
> for (i = 0; i < dynamicComp.length; i++) { 
>     console.log(dynamicComp[0].getType());
> }
> ```

Comment: Sorry, that's not about it. There is no component yet to add id. Let's say that there is just NS3:MyTestComponent available in org. So my logic need to check that NS1:MyTestComponent is not valid type, than NS2:MyTestComponent is not valid type, and after that go and create NS3:MyTestComponent - since it's the only valid one. But untill creation moment component is not available in markup.

Comment: Now i see. You were asking: how to check that aura type is a valid type in provided org. I think it can be achieved with metadata api. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_auradefinitionbundle.htm

Answer (score 1):

You can query AuraDefinitionBundle, like this:

[SELECT NamespacePrefix, DeveloperName FROM AuraDefinitionBundle WHERE DeveloperName = 'My Test Component']

And then return to your lightning component the list of all the components that exist in the org, to help your JS code select which component to create.

Comment: Yep, one of the options, agree. But I wanna try to avoid making server call for that (at least explicitly).

Comment: You could also handle it in the callbacks for the createComponent(). I don't think an exception will get thrown if the component doesn't exist, but the status on the callback would be error or something similar. Then you could retry with the next component.

Comment: The funny thing is that neither exception nor error callback is called when invalid component type is passed to createComponent function - from my practical experiments. I adore SalesForce)

Comment: @wesaw you won't be able to avoid server side calls - if component dependency is not declared, `$A.createComponent()` will do a server call to retrieve that component from the org. In fact, pre-querying could be more efficient if you try to create more than one component. Finally, correct me if I am wrong, but your actual problem is finding/enumerating the right namespace?